# JQuery DataTables not working in my Struts Application

Tags: jquery, datatables

i am new in Jquery DataTables i am first time using them ,i have implemented in my jsp page i am using struts 1.3 but its not working nothing coming i am not understanding what is actually happening its just showing only data, no filter,no pagination, no sorting ,no search bar nothing is coming
i have downloaded DataTables 1.8

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
      <title>Room List</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="DataTables/media/js/jquery.js">      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"      src="DataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
      <link href="DataTables/media/css/Beautiful.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#room_id').dataTable();
         
          } );
          
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <%@include file="Header.jsp" %> 
      <% 
         ArrayList list = (ArrayList)request.getAttribute("list");
         
         %>
      <table id="room_id" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="pretty">
         <tr>
            <td>Code</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Floor Name</td>
            <td>Location Name</td>
         </tr>
         <%
            for (int index=1; index<list.size(); index++) { 
            RoomBean room =(RoomBean)list.get(index);
            %>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <%=room.getcode()%>
            </td>
            <td>
               <%=room.getname() %>
            </td>
            <td>
               <%=room.getfloorname() %>
            </td>
            <td>
               <%=room.getlocationname() %>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <% } %>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

where iam doing wrong i am not understaning
any help would a great hint for me as i am using it first time

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrectly formed table. To apply datatables plugin, your table must have thead and tbody sections where are laced rows.

Regards,
Jovan